# Geometric series not about the origin

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series

Find a simple expression for the power series:

$$\sum_{n = 1}^\infty n(z-1)^{n-1}$$

My question is can i treat this as a geo series and end up with this result:

$$\frac{d}{dz} \frac{1}{1 - (z-1)} $$

Now i know i could simplify the denominator more,  but i left it like that just to relate it to the original expression so you had an idea of how i treated it.

Thanks

Comment: The first series converges to what you think if $\;|z-1|<1\;$ ...Are you given this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is correct.  In order to prove it's correct, one must deal with the following.  From first-semester calculus you know that
$$
\frac d {dz}(A+B+C+\cdots +Z) = \frac {dA}{dz} + \cdots +\frac{dZ}{dz}
$$
when there are only finitely many terms.  But it doesn't always work with infinitely many terms.  However, it does work with *power series* as long as you remain in the interior of the interval of convergence.  That follows from the fact that on sets bounded away from the boundary of the region of convergence, the pointwise convergence of power series is actually uniform.  And one goes into the way in which uniform convergence relates to differentiation.  So one could consider the argument given in the question incomplete unless a theorem about term-by-term differentiation of power series is at least cited.